# Firebase Realtime Database getting duplicate data on adding, updating or removing an item Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

i got stuck while trying to read data from firebase on add, update or remove an item. When ever i do one of 3 operations. What it does is: duplicate the data had before and add new values. I am using ‘values’ event listener to read from firebase.

When i add in firebase  a new Data (In this case i added firebase), the Google data Duplicate in two. It was created before in the firebase. But if i reload the page, then it show correctly. Just show one Google Data.

I can't figure out where is the error, is it the 'value' event listener?

That is the result i get when add, update or remove an item in firebase.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcpNx.png

Vuex Actions

```
addEvent({getters,commit},payload){
            firebase.database().ref('usuario/'+getters.isAuthenticated.userId+'/eventos/').push(payload)
                .then((event)=>{
                    //Update state changes
                    commit('setEvent',event);
                    router.push('/')
                }).catch(err =>{
                console.log(err.message)
            })
        },
```

Here i read data from firebase with 'value' event listener

```
 getEvents({commit}){
            let events = [];
            firebase.database().ref('usuario')
                .on('value',event =>{
                    event.forEach(user =>{
                        user.child('eventos').forEach(evento =>{
                            events.push({ "id": evento.key, ...evento.val() })
                        })
                    });
                   //Update state changes

                    commit('setEvent',events)
                });
        }
```

Comment: As mentioned on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492209/vuex-state-not-updating-correctly-existing-data-on-adding-new-data-in-firebase), you are adding all the events to your `events` array **each and every time** the `usuario` value changes. That is how Firebase's `.on` works

Comment: @Phil, thanks you so much for your help. But how can i prevent from this. What i want is, on add, update or remove an item from firebase it has to show the changes without reload the page. I think it's not problem of vuex. It's how i am reading data from firebase. Please need help to sort out. I got stuck here.What i have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Define `let events = []` **inside** the `.on` callback

Comment: This is _somewhat_ similar to this post ~ [Vuex - 'do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013298/vuex-do-not-mutate-vuex-store-state-outside-mutation-handlers)

Comment: Thank you so much @Phil. It's worked